# Implementing the modulo operator as a function in C

Tags: c, operators, modulo

How can we implement the modulo operator as a function in C without using the operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`

(C99 standard, 6.5.5/6).

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, it is merely an axiomatic definition of the % operator (and therefore not really "simple").  I am wondering at the number for votes for this.

Comment: @Clifford: Maybe because with an obvious transformation (subtract `(a/b)*b` from both sides) it becomes a formula for determining `a%b`?

Comment: @caf: Maybe, but "simple" would have been to present the "obvious" transformation rather than assume the reader possesses the (albeit basic) mathematical skills.  The mathematical ability of the OP is unknown; to assume that it is obvious may just look like showing off.

Comment: "Without using the operator" aka, do not use the % operator, aka your answer uses the modulo operator, and therefore you didn't answer his question, in fact it's kinda smug...

Comment: This doesn't work. If `a = 15` and `b = 8` you will get correctly `7`. If `a = -15` and `b = 8` you will get `1`. Both should be `7`

Comment: What about with floats? With floats, `(a/b)*b` is always `a`.

Answer (score 41):

Do an integer division followed by a multiplication, and subtract.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int c=8, m=3, result=c-(c/m*m);
  printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: `-21` mod `20` == `-1` in the above code, but it should be `19`. Works only for positives

Answer (score 19):

Here you go:

```
a % b = a - (b * int(a/b))
```

Comment: That cast notation only works in C++ (not C, which the question asks about) and is superfluous if a and b are integers.  But the downvote came from elsewhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, can you please explain which this doesn't work in C.

Comment: @user674669: In C you'd have to write `(int)(a/b)`.  The type-functional notation `int(a/b)` is specific to C++.

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers. -5 modulo 4 should be `3` but `-5 - ((int)(-5/4) * 4)` outputs `-1`.

Comment: @AaronFranke that's not true. in c/c++ `fmod(-5,4)==fmodf(-5,4)==(-5%4)==-1`. you are talking about ((a%b)+b)%b)

Comment: @kritzikratzi The `%` operator, `fmod` function, and `fmodf` function in C++ have the "remainder" behavior of C/C++/C#, not the mathematically correct modulo behavior found in Python's `%` operator.

Comment: @AaronFranke the question _is_ about c :) either way i learned something today: i'm talking about "truncated" division, you are talking about "floored" division. more here, it's fascinating and a grand overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages

Answer (score 8):

You could simulate `x % y` by repeatedly subtracting `y` from `x` and keeping track of the result. At each iteration, if the result is less than `y`, then you have your remainder, and can just return it.

Comment: This can be slow but useful if computer doesn't have multiplication/division capabilities.

Comment: This is not how real software implementations work. A real software implementation would double the second operand until another doubling would make it greater than the first, subtract, and then start dividing the second operand by two and subtracting.

Answer (score 1):

Dividend / Divisor = Quotient

The formula (in Python 3) is below:

Modolus = Divident - Dividend // Divisor * Divisor

For example if the Dividend = 5, and the Divisor = 2, then

Modulus = 5 - 5 // 2 * 2 which becomes
          5 - 2 * 2
          5 - 4
            1
Remember that // has higher precedence than -, so 5 // 2 is
evaluated first.